# How do you set a Vue property to the value of a stringified element attribute?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Forgive me for the very silly question.

I have something like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    words: []
  },
  created() {
    let something = document.getElementById('word_data')
    if (something) { this.words = something.dataset.content.slice() }
  }
})
```

And this is the HTML part:

```
<input type="hidden" id="word_data" data-content="[&quot;one&quot;,&quot;two&quot;,&quot;thee&quot;]">
```

which is just an array in the format of `["one", "two", "three", "four", "etc"]`.

I'm trying to assign this array to `words` in Vue. How can I do this?

If I assign it as it is in my example, it will take the whole array as a single record.

I'm sure it's something very simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the element's `data-content` attribute value, then use `JSON.parse()` to convert it from the format you've provided.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    words: []
  },
  created() {
    const element = document.getElementById('word_data');
    const data = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-content'));
    if (data) { this.words = data }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="word_data" data-content="[&quot;one&quot;,&quot;two&quot;,&quot;thee&quot;]" >

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="word in words">{{word}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: JSON.parse did it. Thank you.

Comment: @Bert Thanks for updating my answer with Vue!

Comment: @user3209270 It's a good bet when you see data stringified like that that `JSON.parse()` will convert it to something useable since almost all run-of-the-mill stringifiers will make something that's JSON-compatible.

Comment: Just a reminder: Vue wants you to use the data driven way, so accessing the DOM (`element.getAttribute('data-content')`) is not the way to go. You should use `v-model` on the input, so you can use the data directly.

Comment: @BennettDams Thanks! Have a look at the revision history (especially the first version) and you'll see this post evolved a bit. Feel free to add another, better answer! I'll just leave this as it is.

Comment: @msanford Well, you can't use the "right" way in your answer as the code of the question itself doesn't contain `v-model` so my comment was referring to OP.

Comment: @BennettDams That's why I invited you to post a completely new answer and demonstrate the correct way of doing it for OP (and future readers), if you wanted. "Hey, you try to access the DOM in your question, but the idiomatic Vue way is like this..."

Comment: OP here, and sure, I'd be interested to see the "right" way to approach this.